# How to connect log4j to loggly on openshift?

Tags: java, log4j, openshift, loggly

Is there a way to connect a java (jboss as) application using log4j to loggly on openshift?

The configuration for log4j where you have full control over the server is configured here: https://www.loggly.com/docs/java-log4j/

But when i run the first step on openshift, I get the following error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an odd article in my eyes, use log4j by installing syslog, hmmmm.
There is no way that would work on Openshift.

I would suggest you follow the logback instructions instead 
https://www.loggly.com/docs/java-logback/

With a slf4j Bridge
http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j

That will enable to log remotely from openshift while only requiring some extra jars and no sudo requirements.